# How to invoke a method in restful web service using camel-cxf?

Tags: rest, apache-camel, cxfrs

I want to invoke a rest service using apache camel. Currently i am using the cxfrs component to configure my endpoint. My route looks like below:

```
from("cxfrs://http://127.0.0.1:8080/RestServiceApp/?resourceClasses="com.sample.Server.HelloWorld").log("Route Started");
```

My problem is that i want to invoke a method present in the server class (HelloWorld in my case). Can you please tell me how do i call a particular method?

Comment: This user has reported the same question on Camel mailing list - http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/RestFul-service-using-camel-td5726656.html

Answer (score 0):

Camel doesn't call resource class methods. From the documentation on the Camel web-site http://camel.apache.org/cxfrs.html:

> This class is used to configure the JAXRS properties ONLY. The methods
>   will NOT be executed during the routing of messages to the endpoint,
>   the route itself is responsible for ALL processing instead.

You need to write a custom processing logic, for example as following:

```
<from uri="cxfrs://http://127.0.0.1:8080/RestServiceApp/?resourceClasses="com.sample.Server.HelloWorld">
<choice>
    <when>
        <simple>${header.operationName} == 'operation1'</simple>
        <to uri="direct:operation1" />
    </when>
    <when>
        <simple>${header.operationName} == 'operation2'</simple>
        <to uri="direct:operation2" />
    </when>
    ....
</choice>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply alexander. But i want to invoke a web service hosted on a remote server. According to the apache cxfrs document, if you want to invoke the REST service through camel-cxfrs producer, then you need to put the operation name in the message header. But if I am doing from(rest_service_route).process(new MyProcessor()) , the processor is never invoked. Kindly help me with that.